# How to replace certain number of elements in each row (different for each row) with zero/NA in R dataframe?

Tags: r, subset

Let the data be in X as follows
 A B C D E F
 1  3  4  6  9 2
 1  2  4  6 8 1
 6  7  9  3  1  3
1  1  2 1  2  7
The number of first n element to be replaced with zero in each row is 
n
2
3
1
4

The resultant matrix should like
 A B C D E F
 0  0  4  6  9 2
 0  0  0  6 8 1
 0  7  9  3  1  3
0  0  0 0  2  7

Which is best way to do it in R? My actual data has around 50 million rows and 120 columns. I might also have to repeat the procedure of replacing with zeros from last column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `row/column` indexing for this

```
X[cbind(rep(1:nrow(X), v1), sequence(v1))] <- 0
X
#   A B C D E F
# 1 0 0 4 6 9 2
# 2 0 0 0 6 8 1
# 3 0 7 9 3 1 3
# 4 0 0 0 0 2 7
```

where

```
v1 <-  c(2, 3, 1, 4)
```